# Weierstrass points in Artin-Schreier extensions of the rational function field in characteristic $p$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, number-fields, ramification, function-fields

I encountered a problem when proving a result regarding the orders at non-Weierstrass points ($n$ is an order of the point $P$ if there is some holomorphic differential $\omega$ with order $n$ at $P$) from Arnaldo Garcia's paper "On Weierstrass Points on Artin-Sehreier Extensions of $k(x)$" [(link to the pdf)](https://www.docdroid.net/hDiXaE9/garcia-pdf#page=2). More specifically, on page 3, the author uses the claim:
[image]

to conclude that:

[image]

I do not see how this result follows from the claim and the author does not explicitly work out the details. This result would follow if we knew that given $a$ an element of $k$ distinct from the $a_i$, there exists an element $b$ in $k$ such that $v_a(y-b)$ (the valuation of $y-b$ at the place corresponding to $a$) is one. In order to prove this, I tried the following argument. Let $a$ be in $k$. Notice that $t^p-t=\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}}$ has a root $b$ in $k$ because of it being algebraically closed. In fact, $b+i$ for all $i\in F_p$ is a root for the polynomial. Thus, we have $\prod_{i\in\mathbb{F_p}}(y-(b+i))=y^p-y-\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}}=\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-a_i)^{m_i}}-\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}}$. I am trying to show that $v_a(y-(b+i))=1$ for some $i$. It can be shown through the triangle inequality that $v_a(y-(b+i))\geq 0$ for all $i\in\mathbb{F}_p$.

We can also use the fact that $f(x)$ has degree less than $m_1+\cdots+m_r$ to conclude that $v_a(\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-a_i)^{m_i}}-\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}})\leq m_1+\cdots+m_r$. However, $x=a$ is a root of $\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-a_i)^{m_i}}-\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}}$. Thus, we must have $1\leq v_a(\frac{f(x)}{\prod_{i=1}^{r}(x-a_i)^{m_i}}-\frac{f(a)}{\prod_{i=1}^{n}(a-a_i)^{m_i}})\leq m_1+\cdots+m_r$. However, I have no idea how to proceed from this point. I am not even certain if this proof strategy would work, but I see no other way of proving the result. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MO! The link in your post has expired; could you perhaps add a bibliographic reference to enable readers to find the paper and look at the context? Thanks.

Comment: @gmvh Thanks for pointing that out. I added another link that should not expire. I also added the title just in case.